# How do I re-ask a question?

Tags: support, asking-questions

Yesterday I asked a question but didn't check on it until today. Today I found out I made a typo in my code which made my question not have sense anymore. Question was heavily downvoted and put on hold. I edited the question and explained what happened and then I wanted to create a new question with the correct code but I couldn't since it was recognized as a duplicate (even if I changed the title and some of it's content). So I cannot re-ask that question. I also cannot delete the original since people already answered to it. And I cannot edit the original question and correct the code since it's downvoted and no one will look at it anymore.

How do I reask my question so I can get some answers?

Comment: Whatever you do, you shouldn't vandalize the [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48406087/can-returning-from-function-by-value-be-undefined-behavior). Replacing the existing content & title with an _"I'm sorry"_ message is not the way to go.

Comment: Important lesson learned: stick to what [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) advices. In particular: "After you post, leave the question open in your browser for a bit, and see if anyone comments. If you missed an obvious piece of information, be ready to respond by editing your question to include it. If someone posts an answer, be ready to try it out and provide feedback!".

Comment: Unfortunately, there has been a spate recently of code that has been maunually transcribed from books or exam/homework papers.   Such code very often has omissions/typos and/or other syntax errors that results in failed compilation/interpretation.  Such code is heavily downvoted, and rightly so, because it wastes the time/effort of everyone involved.  If the OP's had compiled/tested the code first, THEN copy/pasted the code into an SO question, this kind of waste would be avoided.

Comment: I mean, even if you do reask your question, why should the skilled and experienceed developers who answer many questions on SO bother to look at it again?  It may be full of typos again, so best to spend time on another question.  Given the number of questions posted to SO, and the small number of users volunteering time to answer them, you have to get your question right first time, else you will get hammered for it:(

Comment: Your comments seems to say "if you made a mistake the first time then you're **** out of luck and you won't get your answer (ever). That's disappointing.

Comment: @NPS mistake?  It's only my comments here and my aversion to the 'meta effect' that has prevented me from applying a delete vote.  That question is just terribru:(     It's massively disappointing when questions like that are asked.  Where did you get that code from?

Comment: @Justastudent I usually do that but guess what - that's not always possible.

Comment: @NPS If you don't have the time to do that, then you don't have the time to ask a question in the first place. So, just wait until you have time to be able to keep the question open. Trust me; been there, done that,̶ ̶g̶o̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶t̶-̶s̶h̶i̶r̶t̶.

Comment: @Justastudent What if something unexpected comes up? Like a real life situation or whatever. What do I do then? Ignore it because "I posted a question on SO"?

Comment: Wait a minute, I smell a rodent here.  1.7k rep, top tag C++, and a question appears with multiple attempts to return values from a void function?   Please excuse me, but I have to ask....  are you YOU?  Is this a hack?

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, it's called the "typo". Sure, my mistake was not trying to compile it before posting (although I did compile similar code before) but that's still a typo.

Comment: @NPS Of course you wouldn't ignore that, but you already knew that when you just wrote that :-) I'm giving you general advice, don't invalidate that by saying "but in specific cases...". Every rule has exceptions.

Comment: @Justastudent Yes but my point was that **if** something happened I would still get heavily downvoted and heavily criticized even if in such case I wouldn't be able to prevent it.

Comment: @NPS In the rare case that something comes up right after you posted a question, you can always delete the question and undelete it when you get back. This may frustrate people who are answering your question though. In general, a well-researched question shouldn't accumulate downvotes anyway (only minor things may be missing), so investing time before posting a question also helps.

Comment: If going beyond the typo there is a valid question there, I would find it very strange that you were not able to paraphrase title/code/content as to make it different enough in a new question... It is not as if you were question banned or anything.

Comment: Look at this issue from the view of an experienced developer.  A question appears, the inputs/outputs are given and the OP explains why the output is wrong.  A skilled developer hunts through the code for 15 minutes, (€15), decides to try an reproduce the problem, (€30), and then finds out that mismatched brackets cause compilation fail - the code posted was not tested.  Imagine how disheartening that feels.  Time/effort is volunteered, and some OP just flushes it away:(

Comment: A lot of comments here are telling you why the question you posted was a bad one, and why was bad not staying around... but you already know both these things. But I'm at a loss what's preventing you asking you the right question. This one is already a goner, that's clear. But why can't you paraphrase and re-post, this time sans-typo?

Comment: "....but didn't check on it until today" **WHY**!? This is the most frustrating aspect of dealing with questions on the site. If you are going to ask a question and walk away with no intention of being attentive, then you better have either asked a gold standard question that you took days to prepare or be willing to accept that more than likely you did more harm than good.

Answer (score 21):

There are 46 lines of code and two sentences forming a question, showing no research whatsoever.

If you want to repost this verbatim, you don't understand the feedback that question got. It is not only closed and downvoted because it was a non-repro, it's also because it's very poorly researched.

So go back to the drawing board, fiddle some more with your code, reduce it to a single problem and show what you have tried. This will make the question different enough from this one to allow you to post it.

Also, as [pointed out in comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362442/how-do-i-re-ask-a-question#comment551511_362442), very important advice from [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask):

> Post the question and respond to feedback
>
> After you post, **leave the question open in your browser for a bit, and see if anyone comments**. If you missed an obvious piece of information, be ready to respond by editing your question to include it. If someone posts an answer, be ready to try it out and provide feedback!

Apart, of course, from creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which is also mentioned on that page. I'd suggest reading it in its entirety before asking a new question.

Comment: The only thing here that answers my question in this meta SO page is "make it different enough so the system doesn't recognize it". Too bad there's no good way to do it (apparently).

Comment: Obviously and luckily there's no good way to dump a code dump again. It wasn't well-received for a good reason, you'll have to show more effort. I hate saying this, but after asking almost 150 questions you should know better.

Comment: FYI, it wasn't a code dump. I wrote it myself, just copied the functions and changed them since they were all similar.

Comment: It **was** a code dump. You can't drop 50 lines of code without explanation and ask _"Anyone spot any bad practices in here?"_.

Comment: @NPS 'I wrote it myself' you admit to that?  You wrote it and... didn't bother to try and compile it?

Comment: @CodeCaster No, I didn't do that. I provided multiple examples of returning different things by-value from function and asked if any of these is undefined behavior. It wasn't like "anyone spot anything wrong in here", I asked about a concrete issue.

Comment: @NPS you're still missing the point. It doesn't matter if you dumped one or twenty examples, what matters is the phrasing of your question and the research shown. Why would this result in undefined behavior? Why do you think so? What have you tried to answer that question yourself? There is no information like that whatsoever in your question, so it **is** a code dump and "explain to me what's wrong here, if anything".